# iOS Phonegap Media Object - How do I access a resource in the WWW folder?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova

I'm developing an application with phonegap, and I have a sound file I want to play that's in a path like so www/Sounds/sound.mp3, and I'm trying to access this file using the Media object of Phonegap in order to play it.

I cannot figure out the path to access this sound file within a javascript file that uses the Media object? I've tried paths like, file:///www/Sounds/sound.mp3, relative paths, etc and I cannot access it. I keep getting the following error in xcode 4

```
Will attempt to use file resource 'file:///www/Sounds/sound.mp3'
Unknown resource 'file:///www/Sounds/sound.mp3'
```

What path do I need to use to access the file? Or do I need to copy the sound file out of my www directory and into my Resources folder and access it there?

My WWW folder is referenced, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: try `Sounds/sound.mp3` it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Cordova 3.3+, the 2 other answers aren't correct. It should work even if you just pass it a file name.

But, **it will only work in iOS if the file extension is `.wav`**.

This will work:

```
var media = new Media('recording.wav', ...);
```

This won't:

```
var media = new Media('recording.mp3', ...);
```

Comment: So what are the actual changes? we can not play .mp3's on iOS anymore?
and where would it look for 'recording.wav' in your first example? at the www folder? so var media = new Media('sounds/recording.wav', ...); would also work if the wav is in a sounds folder?

Comment: actually looking at the docs for 3.3 I can only find a note saying you can not record anything other then .wav on iOS and not that you can not Play such files.

Comment: This answer is outdated, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175489/ios-phonegap-media-object-how-do-i-access-a-resource-in-the-www-folder/28401652#28401652).

Comment: What if wavs don't work for me either? "Cannot use audio file from resource"

Comment: on iOS nothing is playing here, either mp3 or wav, if I run it in the browser it works

Answer (score 15):

Heres a modified version of getPhoneGapPath that works for me on both iOS and Android. It is also not restricted to only working on files that have a filename that is 10 characters long :)

```
getPhoneGapPath: function () {
    'use strict';
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var phoneGapPath = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    return phoneGapPath;
}

var resource = getPhoneGapPath() + 'audio/audio.mp3';
```

getPhoneGapPath() will return:

**iOS:** /var/mobile/Applications/{GUID}/{appName}/www/

**Android:** /android_asset/www/

Comment: It works on Android. Later I will test it on the iOS system. 
Btw:This page http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.tw/2012/01/on-eleventh-day-of-phonegapping.html also illustrates the almost the same thing as yours. But on the iOS system, he declares the path would be:"".
Thanks for your answer, Ben.

Comment: This is the only solution that has worked for me on both Android and IOS. Thank you.

Comment: This will not work if you are using the HTML5 History API in your program to add in history entries with directories (which use "/").

Comment: Best Solution... Thanks Ben

Answer (score 10):

Use `window.location.pathname` to get the path of your application. It will look something like this on iPhone:

> /var/mobile/Applications/{GUID}/{appname}.app/www/index.html

And this on Android:

> /android_asset/www/index.html

Strip off the `/index.html`, prepend `file://`, and append your relative path `Sounds/sound.mp3`.

Here's something to get you started:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/chNVY/

Code:

```js
function getPhoneGapPath() {

    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.substr( 0, path.length - 10 );
    return 'file://' + path;

};

var resource = getPhoneGapPath() + 'Sounds/sound.mps';
```

Comment: Been looking for this answer for a few hours now. This seems to be the best way that I have seen. Thanks man!

Comment: On iOS, I get "Unknown resource 'file://var/mobile/Applications/{GUID}/{appname}/www/audio/bounce.mp3'"On android, it works, but it returns the path "file:///android_asset/www/

Comment: @BenXTan Does it actually have `{GUID}/{appname}` in the path instead of an actual GUID and an actual app name? The android path is correct.

Comment: window.location.pathname just gives "/index.html" for me, which does not help

Comment: when I try this approach I get :
```
{message: "Cannot use audio file from resource 'file:///var/c…-4B61-91A4-93325E5E75AB/myApp.app/www/song.wav'", code: 1}Object
```

Answer (score 5):

The [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175489/ios-phonegap-media-object-how-do-i-access-a-resource-in-the-www-folder/24761627#24761627) is outdated. You are now able to play `wav`, `mp3`, and `caf` formats on iOS using this "relative path" method:

```
var media = new Media('beep.wav', ...);
```

Note that the above code requires the sound file to be in the root of your `www/` directory -- in this example at `www/beep.wav`. If you want to put them in a subdiretory like `www/sounds/`, you'll need to specify it using a path relative to your `www/` directory. For example, this also works now:

```
var media = new Media('sounds/beep.wav', ...);
```

for the sound file at `www/sounds/beep.wav`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and all the answers about file paths alone didn't work for me using the **Phone Gap Developer app**. The problem was with the Developer app not pushing the files physically onto the device, preventing me from accessing them in any way.

The Media plugin worked as intended using

> $ phonegap run android
>
> $ phonegap run ios

with this js code:

```js
function getPhoneGapPath() {
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  var phoneGapPath = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
   return phoneGapPath;
}
var sound = new Media(getPhoneGapPath()+"assets/sounds/sound.mp3"
//...
sound.play();
```

This returns an error on Developer app:

*'Cannot use audio file from source var/mobile/Containers/data/Application/{GUID}/Library/NoCloud/**phonegapdevapp**/www/assets/sounds/sound.mp3'*

but works if built from the console.

Details can be found here:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2135718

Answer (score 0):

Better try this to take into account any HTML5 History API code that might add in history entries with directories ("/"):

```
function get_phonegap_path () {
 var path = window.location.pathname
 return path.slice(0, path.indexOf("/www/") + 5)
}
```